# SQL Server - cannot find the *.mdf file after detaching

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created new database in SQL Server 2012 `(LocalDb)\v11.0` and detached it. After that, I cannot find the detached file. But with other server, I detach and file appear normally. What happened to my file ?

Comment: **Very first link** from my Google search: [LocalDB: Where is my database file?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx)

Comment: I have found my solution myself. Thank you!